# Rotating Or Slide Show in PHP and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Working with images which are loaded from MySQL database, does anyone have an idea of simple rotating banner framework I can use? I'm looking for simple simple that will allow the visitor to see a series of images rotate, and when one of those images is clicked, it takes them to the detail page for that image.

I've done most of the things above, what I'm after is an image rotator.
Would appreciate your helps with a pointer. Any thing at all would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).  It's very easy to use and has plenty of room for customization.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial I found very useful for image rotators](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/automatic-image-slider-w-css-jquery/).

For the pointer, I would suggest that you use the images inside anchers as the following:

```
<a href="http://example.com/post/awesome"><img src="awesome.png" alt="I'm awesome" /></a>
```

which would make you generate a PHP output like this in a for loop:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $description; ?>"></a>
```